# Открывается два окна при обновлении контента блока "Поделиться" через API

Tags: jquery, ajax, ya-share2

При нажатии на заголовок новости, я пытаюсь обновить контент диалогового окна, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Поделиться" в диалоговом окне появлялся контент выбранной новости.

Проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку вызывается сразу несколько диалоговых окон.

Вот код функции, которая выводит новость и обновляет контент кнопок соц. сетей:

```
<div id="ya-share1" class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki"></div>



$(document).on('click', '.news', function () {
    selectNews();
});

function selectNews() {
    $.post('php/select_news.php').done(function (data) {
        var share1 = Ya.share2('ya-share1', {
            content: {
                url: 'http://babys-joy.ru/news'              
            }
        });

        share1.updateContent({
            url: 'http://babys-joy.ru/news'
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае блок инициализируется при каждом вызове функции `Ya.share2`.

Инициализацию достаточно выполнить один раз, а в теле функции оставить только вызов метода обновления контента:

```
var share1 = Ya.share2('ya-share1', {
    content: {
        url: 'http://babys-joy.ru/news'              
    }
});

function selectNews() {
    $.post('php/select_news.php').done(function (data) {
        share1.updateContent({
            url: 'http://babys-joy.ru/news'
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: сделал, как вы посоветовали. Однако все равно вызывает два окна.
Так же я заметил одну особенность если я в блоке с кнопками прописываю класс  ya-share1 вместо ya-share2 , то все вроде норм - вызывается одно окно.

Comment: @amijin Класс `ya-share2` используется для _автоматической_ инициализации. Если вам нужно динамически менять контент (и вы инициализируете блок через API), указывать этот класс не нужно.